# Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous functions on an interval $[a,b]$ such that, $\int_a^bf(t)dt=2\int_a^bg(t)dt$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous functions on an interval $[a,b]$ such that,
$$\int_a^bf(t)dt=2\int_a^bg(t)dt$$

Show that there exists $c\in[a,b]$ such that $f(c)=2g(c)$.

I used the mean integral theorem, but I didn't come to any conclusions.

And the value of $c$ for being $a$ and $b$ ?

Comment: Define $F(x):= \int_a^x(f(t)-2g(t))dt$ for $x \in [a,b].$ Now use Rolle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the function $h(x):=f(x)-2g(x)$. You have

$$\int_a^b h(x)\ \mathrm dx=\int_a^b f(x)\ \mathrm dx-2\int_a^b g(x)\ \mathrm dx =0.$$

So $h$ is a function with null average, so by the mean integral theorem you get that there exists a $c∈[a,b]$ such that $h(c)=0$ and so $f(c)-2g(c)=0$.